# При использовании iOS-Slide-Menu не работают свайпы

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swipe

Работаю с такой вот менюшкой [iOS-Slide-Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu).

Суть проблемы в том, что не работают свайпы. Создаю новый контроллер, ставлю на него UIImageView, включаю на ней usersIteraction. и при свайпах ничего не работает.

Ставлю на этот view контроллер Is Initial View Controller - все свайпы обрабатываются.

Свайпы пробовал добавлять, как через сториборд, так и в коде. Результат один, с менюхой не работают, без - всё отлично.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решён. Может кому пригодится: 
Данная проблемы и схожие с ней решаются при помощи gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognize